# How keep async uploaded file(s) in a CRUD .NET MVC without Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, file-upload

I have a CRUD where user can upload some files asynchronously...

So I have 2 POST actions : one for the upload (where I save that file on disk) and the other to save the crud entity.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
   // Save file on disk
   // Save the name and other file info on session (?!?)
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyViewModel vm)
{
   // Check the file info on Session
   // Save Entity with file(s) associated
}
```

I´m using Session to keep file info between two POSTs. But with that I have problem using several tabs at same time. And I hate using session at all...

Is there a better option to that problem?

I saw some people using a static variable on controller (http://damienbod.wordpress.com/2013/09/03/mvc-async-file-upload/) . Is that a good approach?

Thanks

Comment: The blog reference you have about a static variable on the controller should be avoided for your scenario. It will not work for multiple users (with regards to associating file uploads to a specific tab as well as general thread safety).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to decide what you want those files to be associated with.  Session would be the current browsing session.

It sounds like you want the files to be associated with the form that is currently loaded and nothing else.  In that case create a GUID when you create the form, load it as a hidden input and then save the GUID with the files.

If the user reloads the form, they would get a new GUID and thus any previously uploaded files wouldn't be associated with the new form.  But if you don't want the files to associate across tabs, that sounds like what you want.

Comment: I can have an entity with several files. And some of than with custom information...

Comment: That's fine.  The GUID is temporary and only exists to associate the files with the entity.  When they submit the form to create the entity you save the entity, get it's ID, then fetch the files using the temporary GUID and update them with the real ID of the entity.